# Python update excel spreadsheet links

Tags: python, excel

I have python code to open excel, then save and exit but I am struggling to find the right python code for a key interim step - once python opens my spreadsheet what is the code to "edit links" and then "update values" before saving the spreadsheet? Please note this is not the same as wb.RefreshAll()  My code with the missing interim step is below:

```
import win32com.client
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open('C:/myfilepathname/test.xlsm')
#what code goes here to select edit links and update them all.

wb.Save()
xlapp.Quit()
```

Thanks

Comment: I should have added, the spreadsheet I want to open has links to other spreadsheets. Opening the sheet via python using the above code does not update these links to other sheets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I decided instead to create a macro in the existing spreadsheet that updates the external links and to call that macro from python as follows:

```
import os
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:/myfilepathname/test.xlsm", ReadOnly=1)
xl.Visible = True
xl.Application.Run("mymacro")
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: How do you create your macro for updating links?